# javax.servlet cannot be resolved even after adding the servlet jar file to the project

Tags: eclipse, servlets, buildpath

I am doing a small web project. I am using eclipse luna, apache tomcat v7.
I am getting the error `cannot resolve java.servletx`. I have added the servlet jar file to the project. Still not able to find out what the issue is.

Comment: check whether the jar is loaded in your project?

Comment: the jar is loaded to the correct project. Still cant the servlet file cant be resolved. Pretty much tried all i know.

Comment: Check whether the servlet-api.jar file is present in the lib folder of your tomcat